# Универсальный способ ловить onFocus и onBlur на странице

Tags: html, javascript

Всем здрасте! На странице много полей и писать в каждое из них:

```
\onFocus="Функция(this);" onBlur="Функция(this);"
```

как то глупо. Поэтому нужна функция по типу:

```
window.onclick = function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
}
```

Только которая вызывает `console.log`(элемент) при onFocus и/или `onBlur`.
Я думал сначала сделать через for и присвоить всем textarea на странице нужную функцию в onFocus и onBlur, но на странице новые поля появляются динамически, и приходится после появления поля снова запускать функцию.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, универсальный способ ловить onFocus и onBlur на странице!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мудрые в инете [говорят](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html#link3), что если включить capture, то работает:

```
document.body.addEventListener('blur',function(e) {
   console.log(e); 
},true); //use capture!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4u8Qx/

Не знаю как там насчет поддержки IE